# How can I write something above and below the signs?

Tags: math-mode, math-operators

I have a relation called Likelihood Ratio Test which has a special format. As you see in the picture, there are two non-equality signs and also somethings above and below them. How can I write these symbols? [image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use a `\Vectorstack`, where the baselineskip of the stack may be set to the desired value.  As Bernard points out, a `\Vectorstack` is actually a `\Centerstack` that is automatically processed in math mode.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{document}
\[
  \setstackgap{L}{.7\baselineskip}
  \Lambda(y) = \frac{p(y{\mid}H_1)}{p(y{\mid}H_0)}
  \Vectorstack{H_1 > < H_0}
  \lambda.
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why not `\Vectorstack`? I thought `\Centerstack` was rather for text.

Comment: @Bernard Teaching me about my own package.  I should either be **im**pressed or **de**pressed.  Using a `\Vectorstack` in lieu of the `\Centerstack` indeed allows one to eliminate the `\stackMath` directive.

Comment: +1 especially for the `{}` around `\mid`, I'll put that in my list of tricks.

Comment: @Rmano Thanks.  Don't forget the corresponding trick, that of forcing the introduction of the space, with `{}\mid{}`.  Compare, for example, x\mbox{$\mid$}x` to `x\mbox{${}\mid{}$}x`.

Answer (score 24):

I propose using `\gtrless` of `amssymb`, to begin with.

The “official” way would be

```
\underset{H_0}{\overset{H_1}{\gtrless}}
```

but the effect is the same with more efficient code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\newcommand{\LRT}[2]{%
  \mathrel{\mathop\gtrless\limits^{#1}_{#2}}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\Lambda(y)=\frac{p(y\mid H_1)}{p(y\mid H_0)} \LRT{H_1}{H_0} \lambda
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

You can stack these using a regular `array`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\[
  \Lambda(y) = \frac{p(y \mid H_1)}{p(y \mid H_0)}
  \begin{array}{c}
    H_1 \\ > \\ < \\ H_0
  \end{array}
  \lambda.
\]

\end{document}
```