# Equivalence of sequence: \sim with some text under

Tags: math-operators

The sign `\sim` is used in mathematics for equivalence of sequences. How to do it in LaTeX?

I tried

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator{\isEquivTo}{\sim}

\begin{document}
\[
\sin(n) + n \isEquivTo\limits_{+\infty} n
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

but the output is not what I am looking for. I would like the `+\infty` to be under the `\sim` sign. Is it possible to have a command `\isEquivTo` that would automatically put the `+\infty` under the sign, without even typing `\limits`?

Comment: Use `\underset{+\infty}{\sim}`; don't use `\DeclareMathOperator`, which would set the wrong spacing for a relation symbol.

Comment: Possible duplicates: [Is there an "underscript" command?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35081/5764); [How can I write something above and below the signs?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/273003/5764); [How to add text under symbol in equation ?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13209/5764)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want an operator to respect `\limits` you should use `\DeclareMathOperator*`. However, this is the wrong tool for the required symbol, because it would make an operator rather than a relation symbol, with wrong spacing. Then

```
\newcommand{\isEquivTo}[1]{\underset{#1}{\sim}}
```

seems better for your needs. Note that `\underset` will “know” that `\sim` is a relation symbol, so it will use the right spacing around it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\isEquivTo}[1]{\underset{#1}{\sim}}

\begin{document}
\[
\sin(n) + n \isEquivTo{+\infty} n
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

On the other hand, setting the subscript under the symbol won't give good results when inline; here's a better definition that uses `\underset` only in display style. Look carefully at the output to see why it's better not using the `\underset` form for inline formulas.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\isEquivTo}[1]{%
  \mathpalette\isEquivToInner{#1}%
}
\newcommand{\isEquivToInner}[2]{%
  \ifx#1\displaystyle
    \underset{#2}{\sim}
  \else
    \sim_{#2}
  \fi
}

\begin{document}
some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text
some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text
$\displaystyle\sin(n) + n \isEquivTo{+\infty} n$
some text some text some text some text some text some text some text
some text some text some text some text some text some text some text
$\sin(n) + n \isEquivTo{+\infty} n$
some text some text some text some text some text some text some text
some text some text some text some text some text some text some text
\[
\sin(n) + n \isEquivTo{+\infty} n
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want a syntax like `\isEquivTo_{+\infty}`, you can do it with `xparse`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\isEquivTo}{e{_}}{\isEquivToA#1}
\NewDocumentCommand{\isEquivToA}{m}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}
    {\sim}
    {\mathpalette\isEquivToB{#1}}%
}
\newcommand{\isEquivToB}[2]{%
  \ifx#1\displaystyle
    \underset{#2}{\sim}
  \else
    \sim_{#2}
  \fi
}

\begin{document}
Here is the command without subscript $n \isEquivTo n$

some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text
some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text
$\displaystyle\sin(n) + n \isEquivTo_{+\infty} n$
some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 
$\sin(n) + n \isEquivTo_{+\infty} n$
some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 
\[
\sin(n) + n \isEquivTo_{+\infty} n
\]
\end{document}
```

You will see that the first call just does `\sim`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I wish I could simply use $\isEquivTo_{...}$ instead of a command.

Comment: My intention is not to argue with you. Actually, my true goal is to redefine `\sim` and use it as `\sum` for instance...

Comment: @Colas What's the conceptual difference between `\isEquivTo_{...}` and `\isEquivTo{...}`? However, I added it. Please, state your problems in full.