# Two questions about the stackengine package:

Tags: math-mode, math-operators, stackengine

Borrowing from [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/273003/how-can-i-write-something-above-and-below-the-signs), I constructed the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{document}
\[
  \setstackgap{L}{.7\baselineskip}
  \setstackgap{S}{9\baselineskip}
  \Vectorstack{H_1 > < H_0}
\]

\[
  \setstackgap{L}{.7\baselineskip}
  \Vectorstack{\alpha > < H_0}
\]

\[
  \setstackgap{L}{.7\baselineskip}
  \Vectorstack{\alpha\\ > < H_0}
\]
\end{document}
```

which produces the output below

[image]

My first question is:  why doesn't the command `\setstackgap{S}{9\baselineskip}`  result in a huge gap between the items in the first display?  As far as I can tell, I'm using `setstackgap` exactly as in the manual.

My second question is:  why is `H_1`  treated differently from `\alpha`?    I.e., when I simply replace `H_` with  `\alpha` to obtain the second display,  in the output, there is no space between `\alpha` and `>`; to get a space I need in the third display to type `\alpha\\`.     Why this difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `\Vectorstack` is a Long-type stack, and so you will find that setting `\setstackgap{L}{}` will change the interline baselineskip of a `\Vectorstack`, whereas a `\setstackgap{S}{}` will have no effect on a `\Vectorstack`. (As a reminder, a long-stack sets the baselineskip between stacked rows, whereas a short-stack sets the size of the dead-zone [empty] gap between row data.)

As to why `H_1` acts differently than `\alpha`, the reason is because the default line separator in `stackengine` is a space.  When you type `H_1 blah`, the space after the `1` is recognized as a space and interpreted as a linebreak in a stack.  However, `\alpha blah` will not recognize the space after `\alpha` as a space, but as the terminator of `\alpha`.  That is not a behavior of `stackengine` per se, but of LaTeX.

The easiest way is to change the end-of-line separator of `stackengine` with, for example, `\setstackEOL{\\}`. Then, you would use `H_1 \\ blah` and `\alpha \\ blah` to create two rows.  However, if you choose to retain the space as the stack EOL character, then `\alpha{} blah` could be used to cause the space before `blah` to be recognized.

The MWE below compares long and short stacks, as well as adding `{}` after `\alpha`...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
\[
  \setstackgap{L}{1.7\baselineskip}
  \setstackgap{S}{3\baselineskip}
  \Vectorstack{H_1 > < H_0}\quad
  \Shortstack{H_1 > < H_0}
\]

\[
  \setstackgap{L}{1.7\baselineskip}
  \Vectorstack{\alpha > < H_0}\quad
  \Vectorstack{\alpha{} > < H_0}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]