# Write some text under physic-chemistry formula

Tags: math-mode, formatting

How can I write some text under a formula? The effect I would like to achieve is the following

[image]

I would like the two words, "prodotti" and "reagenti", to be placed *under* each summation.

Comment: Look for underset command in stackengine package I guess.

Comment: @user202729 That's in `amsmath`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\Delta_\mu G^\phi = \underset{\text{prodotti}}{\sum \nu \Delta_f G^\phi} - \underset{\text{reagenti}}{\sum \nu \Delta_f G^\phi}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, exactly what I was looking for!
P.S. Is \mu actually the underscore for gibbs free energy reaction?

Comment: @user3713179 I don't know, in fact I have no idea what this equation is supposed to mean. I just thought I read a `\mu` on the picture.

Comment: @user3713179 From what I see looking around, it should be `\Delta_{\mathrm{r}}`

Answer (score 2):

Inspired from this old question [Two questions about the stackengine package:](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/361326/two-questions-about-the-stackengine-package) you can obtain the same result of `\underset`. Note that `\setstackgap{S}{3pt}` it is important to put the text more below (see the parameter `3pt`}.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\stackMath
\setstackgap{S}{3pt}
\begin{document}
\[\Delta_{r} G^{\phi}=\stackunder{ \displaystyle\sum \nu \Delta_f G^\phi}{\textup{ prodotti}} - \stackunder{\displaystyle\sum \nu \Delta_f G^\phi}{\textup{reagenti}}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\stackMath
\setstackgap{S}{2pt}
\begin{document}
\[\Delta_{r} G^{\phi}=\stackunder{ \displaystyle\sum \nu \Delta_f G^\phi}{\textup{ \scriptsize prodotti}} - \stackunder{\displaystyle\sum \nu \Delta_f G^\phi}{\textup{\scriptsize reagenti}}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]